# extract names in a list of names

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, nltk, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I have been provided with a text cleaning task and I am assuming this involves some amount of natural language processing.

I have  a collection of names which does not have any specific pattern and I need to separate individual names from that list.

Below is an example:

```
John Batista Barack Obama George W. Bush Serafim Batzoglou Vijay Pande Fei Fei Li Oussama Khatib Kwame Nkrumah John Oliver
```

As you can see there are two things peculiar with the paragraph.

1) space " " is the only delimiter, however, it is unusable as there are names which have middle names.

2) I have french, German, Spanish, Chinese and other ethnic sounding names written in English.

Now the challenge I am facing is to find names from this paragraph. I am very new to NLP and use Python and R for modeling work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert here, so here's my (brute force?) method.

SeatGeek has open-sourced a python library called [fuzzywuzzy](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/) which is great at text matching.  It has a function called `token_set_ratio` that compares two multi-word strings and scores their distance.  It can consider just the intersection of individual words and score only that intersection. eg "Barack Obama Bill Clinton Madeleine Albright" will get a score of 100 with "Bill Clinton", but also with "Bill Barack".

You'll need to build a list of known names, judging by the list they're famous people, which a quick google search shows hundreds of sites that have that ready for you.  With that list, you can just loop your way through, computing a score with `token_set_ratio`.  If the famous name beats some threshold score against your string, you append it to a list of captured names.

Comment: Alternatively, if your list is literally just [First Name] [Middle Initial (optional)] [Last Name], you could just string split on " ", throw out all elements with a regex [A-Z]\., and then take pairs.

Comment: Did you suggest using fuzzylogic?